# NewtonSoft.Json JsonConvert Deserialize error

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have serialized a complex object( containing abstract classes, read only properties) using Newtonsoft.Jsonconverter SerializeObject successfully. 
While trying to Deserialize the same using DeserializeObject method, it throws following error
 - An item with this key has already been added.
On further investigation I found out that there might be some properties in the object with same name. But I couldn't find any property name being repeated in json file being de-serialized.

Version of NewtonSoft Json : 8.0.3

Comment: Can you post relevant code snippets, maybe examples of Json.

Comment: Can you elaborate with what have you tried. Here are some related Queries which might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096427/can-i-make-a-strict-deserialization-with-newtonsoft-json?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147989/error-deserializing-a-json-string-into-a-composite-object?rq=1

Comment: Can you post the code , or check your class may be in base class same name property exist if it is so use hide those property in your class with the help of new keyword.

Comment: My class structure is as follows
ClassXyz : BaseClass1, IClonable
BasClass1:BaseClass2 , The BaseClass2 is an abstract calss.

All these classes(ClassXyz,BaseClass1 and BaseClass2) contains the properties which are of some other class types. Also few properties are read only.
The total number of classes involved in forming this object is 12. ( as property, derived class, base class etc)

I have used Newtonsoft.Json to serialize this object to Json. It did convert to json successfully.
While converting back the json to .net object I got the error mentioned in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was trying to replicate your error but actually what I got was a successful result. this is the test I did :

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var child = new Child();
            var serializesObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(child);

            var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializesObject, typeof(Child));
        }        
    }

    public abstract class Abstract
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public readonly string Prop2;
        public List<string> Prop3 { get; set; }
        public int[] Prop4 { get; set; }

        public abstract void Hey();

        public Abstract()
        {
            Prop1 = 1;
            Prop2 = "2";
            Prop3 = new List<string>();
            Prop4 = new int[4];
        }
    }

    public class Child : Abstract
    {
        public readonly string Prop5;

        public Child()
        {
            Prop5 = "5";

        }
        public override void Hey()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this code can help you to get to the expected result you want.

Cheers,

Comment: The problem does persist though. Does it pose any issue while de-serializing if we have a property with name "RuntimeInfo" ? this property is of type RuntimeInfo class.
If I rename this property to RuntimeInfo1 it gets de-serialized successfully.

Comment: Can anyone let me know how can I find which key is getting repeated in my dictionary which is causing "An item with this key has already been added" during Deserialization.

Comment: Hi @Kaveesha, where this class RuntimeInfo comes from?